# Mixing PDO and MySQL Functions?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

On the existing system its use old MySQL functions.. I would like to replace it all to PDO but it would take a long time and a lot of testing.

Is it possible to mix PDO and MySQL Functions on the existing system? For example new pages/php files will use PDO... All the old files will still use old MySQL for time being and will be replaced slowly as system will continue to update..

Comment: +1 for making the effort to switch to pdo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly fine to use both at the same time. Keep in mind, though, that you would need a [seperate connection for either type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316413/getting-a-php-pdo-connection-from-a-mysql-connect) and beware of the [implications that arise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788238/mixing-old-mysql-with-pdo?rq=1) from such an approach.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to SO but I have faced this problem too. Many people find it troublesome to switch from `mysql_*` to PDO.
In my case I was using a separate `connection.php` that stored functions to connect to database and returned the handle

```
function connect() 
{ 
    $cn = mysql_connect("localhost","username","pass" );
    $select = mysql_select_db("dbname", $cn);
    return($cn);
}

//For PDO
function pdoconnect()
{
    $db="";
    try
    {
        $db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname", "username", "pass");
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    catch (PDOException $er)
    {
        print("errr".$er."<br />");
        return(1);
    }
    return($db);
}
```

while for old functions I used `$cn=connect();`.
I switched to `$cn=pdoconnect();` for new ones.

**This worked because I was already using `connect.php` in old files as well.**

Comment: When you replaced `$cn=connect();` I switched to `$cn=pdoconnect();` - you still have to replace `mysql_query()` to PDO `prepare()`, `execute()` functions right?

Comment: You clearly are a very experienced programmer, I would be more than glad to know new ways